# Hexagon to Rectangle dissection: 3 pieces minimal?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, plane-geometry, dissection

A hexagon can be divided into 3 pieces to make a rectangle.
[image]

Can we prove 3 pieces is minimal?

For a equilateral triangle to square dissection, it's thought that 4 pieces is minimal. We can prove that at least 3 pieces are needed by the pigeonhole principle. With just 2 pieces, one of the length $2/\sqrt[^4]{3} = 1.51967$ edges of the unit area triangle must fit on the unit area square, but that's impossible. Therefore, at least three pieces are needed for dissecting an equilateral triangle into a square.

Is there a proof that a regular hexagon cannot be cut into 2 pieces to make a rectangle?

Update: an [NJA Sloane paper](http://neilsloane.com/doc/Rectangle3.pdf).

Comment: Any constraints on the cut? Does it have to be a straight line? (I'm not sure it would help much, but useful to know) My thoughts on this would be that any such proof would rely on the number of right angles you can make (it - probably - can't rely on lengths as we're looking at a rectangle, not a square). It may also be easier to prove that a rectangle can't be cut into two pieces to make a hexagon; it's somewhat easier to visualise.

Comment: Any sort of cut is allowed.